# Aframe not working with Vive and Firefox on Windows 10

Tags: firefox, aframe, steam, webvr, htc-vive

I can't get to work my code or even the examples provided on http://aframe.io/examples/ on HTC Vive and Firefox 59.0.2 (Windows 10 on a MSI laptop computer with GTX 1060, Geforce drivers 3.13.1.30). Tried also with Firefox Nightly.

The scene loads and the controllers are visible. The headset is not tracked and does not change the scene. Then SteamVR starts and shows a "firefox.exe unresponsive" message. From this point, if I enter VR mode, the headset is not tracked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to NVIDIA Control Panel and set Firefox to use with High Performance Mode. The laptop is probably falling back to integrated graphics.

If you use a VR browser like Supermedium, this is automatically handled for you.